# Use current user environment variable in sudoers file

Tags: sudo, users

I want some of my users to be able to change their password with sudo command because at the time they log in, they are passwordless (ssh keys connection). My users have no password (and this is wanted), they can't `sudo` anything. Nevertheless, I want them to be able to do only one sudo command: `sudo passwd $USER`, so they can choose a password.

Here is the interesting parts of my sudoers file:

```
Defaults!/usr/bin/passwd    env_keep=SUDO_USER

%restrictedgroup ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd $SUDO_USER
```

It doesn't work. How can I access the current SUDO_USER environnement variable in sudoers file?

EDIT: I have another important contraint in my context: I can't set a dummy password to every single users. It means they really can't change their password without `sudo`.

Comment: Why not just ask them to run `passwd`? You don't need `sudo` to change your own user's password.

Comment: @terdon Yes, they need `sudo`. You can't change a password if you don't have one previously set, unless you are root (or sudo). That's why.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed. Would setting a silly password like `pass` and then having them change it be an option?

Comment: I thought about that. But then, imagine I'm user3, and I log in first. I change my password, and because I know everybody's password (the silly pass), I can `su`. Of course, another solution is to make a different silly password to everyone, but this is my contraint: I can't do that easily in my context.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script (say `/usr/local/bin/change-my-pass.sh`):

```
#! /bin/sh    
passwd $SUDO_USER
```

And add that to the `sudoers`, then either tell your users (or give them a welcome message instructing them) to use that script.

Comment: Good solution, thanks. That solve my problem, but I'm still curious about a way to get environment variables in sudoers.